# To make something become rare

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Is there a (formal register) verb meaning "to make something become rare"? In context, I would like to say "The new software will make instances/situations where you have to manually update database files rare."

The obvious bet would be "rarefy", but I suspect it does not quite capture that meaning. "Reduce" etc. also doesn't quite seem to fit the bill, does it?

Comment: ***Minimize***: To reduce to the smallest possible amount, extent, size, or degree.

Comment: *Situations requiring manual update of database files will be **exceptional**, rather than routine, with the new software*.

Answer (score 1):

Though this is used mostly in the context of retirement from the workplace, of being "made redundant," it fits your criteria quite closely:

**superannuate** (v.)

> 2. To set aside or discard as old-fashioned or obsolete.

(AHD, 4th edition)

Or a less formal option:

**phase out** (v.)

> 1. (idiomatic) To remove or relinquish the use of something little by little.
>
> *Leaded petrol was phased out in the course of the 1990s.*

([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/phase_out))

Comment: _Phase out_ doesn’t quite work in the context given here, though I can’t really put into words what it is about it that jars. Something about manually updating database files never being a feature, always a necessary evil. _Superannuate_ in the sense you cite is more or less synonymous with _supersede_, and again it implies that some feature is replacing another previous feature, which doesn’t quite fit here. Here instead, we have an improved piece of software (not a specific feature, but the software in general) that reduces the necessity of a formerly common source of annoyance.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet If *"It's not a bug, it's a feature"* is a thing then *"It's not a necessary evil, it's a feature"* should be too.

Answer (score 0):

If the software will eliminate the need to do something, it *obviates* the need. If it doesn't entirely eliminate the need to do something, it makes the need *all but a thing of the past*.

Answer (score 0):

winnow: to reduce a large number of people or things to a much smaller number by judging their quality

Cambridge Dictionaries Online

"The new software will winnow [out] the manual update of database files"

Answer (score 0):

The new software will **[curtail](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/curtail)** (the number of) such instances.

> **Reduce in** extent or **quantity**; impose a restriction on (Oxford)

From the definition and quoted examples on [Vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/curtail), you can see that the both the meaning and the usage contexts meet your requirements.

> To curtail something is to slow it down, put restrictions on it, or stop it entirely. If I give up cake, I am curtailing my cake-eating.
>
> Curtail is an **official-sounding word for stopping** or slowing things down. The police try to curtail crime — they want there to be less crime in the world. A company may want to curtail their employees' computer time, so they spend more time working and less time goofing around. Teachers try to curtail whispering and note-passing in class. **When something is curtailed, it's either stopped entirely or stopped quite a bit — it's cut short.**
>
> Example: *It also said future growth could be curtailed without greater investment in transportation infrastructure*